# Ionic 2 public object array doesn't display in a view

Tags: ionic2

I have a script that retrieve some datas and store it in an array :

```
export class ProductsByArea {
  public products: any;
  public area: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private easyStockService: EasyStockService, 
    private imageProvider: ProductImageProvider,
    private platform: Platform
) 
{
 //this.area = navParams.get('area');
this.easyStockService.getArea(navParams.get('area')).then((doc) => {
  this.area = doc;
  this.getProducts(this.area._id).then((products) => {
    let datas: any;
    datas = products;
    this.products = datas;
  });
});

}
private getProducts(area: any){
let datas: any = [];
let products: Array<any> = [];
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.easyStockService.getProducts(area).then((results) => {
    datas = results;

    let uploadDirectory = this.imageProvider.getUploadDirectory();

    // Boucle sur les produits pour récupérer les données cohérentes
    datas.forEach((data) => {
      let product: any = {};
      product.ean = data._id;
      product.title = data.title;

      if(data.image != 'no-image.png')
        product.image = uploadDirectory + data._id + '.jpg';
      else 
        product.image = 'assets/images/no-image.png';

      product.stock = this._computeStock(data.inStock);

      products.push(product);
    })

    resolve(products);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Erreur lors de la récupération des produits dans la zone : ' + area);
  });

});
```

and...

```
  private _computeStock(inStock:any){
let averagePrice: number = 0;
let totalStock: number = 0;
let lastPurchase: any = null;
let lastOutDate: any = null;
let totalValue: number = 0;

inStock.forEach((stock) => {
  averagePrice += parseFloat(stock.totalPrice) / parseInt(stock.initialQuantity);
  totalStock += parseInt(stock.initialQuantity);
  lastPurchase = moment(stock.purchaseDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  let out = stock.out;
  if(out.length){
    totalStock -= out.quantity;
  }
});

totalValue = totalStock * (averagePrice / inStock.length);

return {'totalStock': totalStock, 'lastPurchaseDate': lastPurchase, 'lastOutDate': lastOutDate, 'totalValue': totalValue};
}
```

Datas are correctly retrieved, but when i want to display them in a view, i got this kind of screen :
[image]

The view code is :

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset id="products-by-area">
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let product of products">
      <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-complex">
          <ion-thumbnail item-left>
              <img src="{{ product.image }}" title="{{ product.title }}" />
          </ion-thumbnail>

          <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
          <ion-note item-end>
            {{ product.ean }}
          </ion-note>    
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="right" *ngIf="product.stock.totalStock > 0">
        <button ion-button color="warning">
          <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
          {{ 'remove' | translate }}
       </button>
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="toTrash(product)";>
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          {{ 'trash' | translate }}
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="success">
          <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
          {{ 'add' | translate }}
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>

      <ion-item-options side="left">
        <button ion-button color="success">
          <ion-icon name="stats"></ion-icon>
          {{ 'stats' | translate }}
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Don't understand why product.title or product.image, or even product.ean are not displayed ?

Try to modify type of the public products property, but... nothing appears, as if the product variable was not an object or an empty object.

I'm new to ionic 2 and really don't understand what it's wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm that your products array and subsequent product objects are being filled? If they are, it's probably an issue with the actual HTML of your project.

Comment: Why are you pushing into an local `products` array? and why are you returning a new promise?

Comment: Confirm that the initial array contains all the products that i need... I consoled the datas before ask the question... For the second point, every product in the array is build in a loop that compute some other datas